# Error: SteamAPI initialization failed. Steam features won't be accessible

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, server

I've put together a docker image for hosting an arma 3 server but every time the server launches I get an error of SteamAPI initialization failed. Steam features won't be accessible! The server looks as if it launches up but I can't find it in the server browser or direct connect to it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or why it's not working but I definitely need some help to get it working.

Here is a link to the log file

```
[logfile](https://pastebin.com/jbBGF2AU)
```

Here are the links to the source files

```
[Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/F70EZEs7)

[launch.py](https://pastebin.com/NbQwPkMV)

[local.py](https://pastebin.com/qyx1Qavd)

[key.py](https://pastebin.com/3kiw5zcW)

[workshop.py](https://pastebin.com/8dSSj0xi)
```